# Getting 5120 X 1440 @ 120Hz on a 2018 Mac mini

Tags: display, thunderbolt, mac-mini, displayport

I recently just purchased a Samsung CRG9, which is a really great monitor. Only problem I have is that I’m not able to get the full 5120 X 1440 at 120Hz that the monitor is rated for. I can get the 5120 X 1440 at 60Hz just fine, but it would be nice to be able to get 120Hz at that resolution as well if possible. I’m using a high-quality DisplayPort 1.4 to Thunderbolt 3 Cable.

Does anyone here know how to do this? Especially if you own this monitor.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the GPU support according to the Apple specifications?

Comment: I don't believe that there are *any* Macs capable of outputting 120Hz, but I could be mistaken

Comment: Please **be specific:** which 2018 Mac mini? Also the Mini uses Intel Integrated Graphics. If I am not mistaken they only support 60Hz. To get a faster refresh rate you need a Mac with a better GPU. Note that this is a limitation of the GPU built into the CPU. You would have to purchase an external GPU, assuming such are available for this Mac.

Comment: Agreed - you might have to get an external GPU connected with thunderbolt

Answer (score 3):

According to [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-3.2-late-2018-specs.html), [The 2018 Mac Mini] 'supports "up to" three displays. It can support either (1) two displays up to 4096x2304 at 60 Hz via Thunderbolt 3 and one display up to 4096x2160 at 60 Hz via HDMI 2.0; OR (2) one display up to 5120x2880 at 60 Hz via Thunderbolt 3 and one display up to 4096x2160 at 60 Hz via HDMI 2.0.'

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP782?locale=en_US) themselves, "Support for the following combination of maximum concurrent display setups:

- Up to three displays:

  - Two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz connected via Thunderbolt 3 plus one display with 4096-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz connected via HDMI 2.0

- Up to two displays:

  - One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz connected via Thunderbolt 3 plus one display with 4096-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz connected via HDMI 2.0

  Thunderbolt 3 digital video output supports Native DisplayPort output over USB-C

  Thunderbolt 2, DVI, and VGA output supported using adapters (sold separately)

  HDMI 2.0 display video output

  Support for one display with 4096-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz

  DVI output using HDMI to DVI Adapter (sold separately)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get my 2018 mac mini working at 5120x1440 @60hz with a high end 15ft cable paired with a USB-C to DP adapter.  I was using SwitchResX but it was not offering a 5120x1440 @60hz option.

I switched to a shorter 10ft cable with no adapter as a test and it worked.

Cable that worked:
https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B06XTYKLNJ/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_V5VQJBH5J392A596SQ78?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1) and it worked in full screen with SwitchResX.