# Can't configure 75hz on LG Ergo Ultrawide monitor with MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I own a:

- **LG Ergo 34WN780** - Ultrawide QHD Monitor - 34 inch
- **MacBook Pro** (15-inch, 2019)
- **StarTech USB-C naar DisplayPort** cable 1,8 metres

The monitor supports `75hz`, but I can only configure it up to `60hz (3440x1440)`.

I've also tried to use the cscreen utility from terminal, but if I set:

```
cscreen -d 32 -x 3440 -y 1440 -r 75 -s 2
```

the monitor turns to `30hz` for some reason, so it's decreasing (although I passed `-r 75)`.

What could be the issue?

Update: I found this on some forum, by someone that bought my same exact monitor: if anyone can confirm would be great:

> " just bought this monitor a few days ago and thought I would share
> some tips for Mac users. If you have a macbook pro I highly recommend
> that you also buy a display port 1.4 to usb c / lightening cable to
> use with this monitor. The included hdmi cable (or any other I've
> tried) will not get you the full 75hz refresh rate on 3440 x 1440.
> Also the display port cable produces a cleaner overall image + text.
> Through hdmi... it was really bad. I mean to the point where it was
> nauseating to read text on my text editor."

Comment: Is the mac limited to 60Hz? Seems like this has been addressed in previous posts.

Comment: @SolarMike which posts? Are you sure you are referring to Hz for external monitor? (not the Macbook monitor)

Comment: I said mac and I meant mac... other posts pointed out it had a 60Hz limit, and those posts were recent to, so a quick search should find them.

Comment: @SolarMike Great, you meant mac then. I did a search of a couple of hours yesterday but I could not find a post/Apple doc specifying the Hz limit for external monitors for a Macbook (via DisplayPort). Maybe you can help? ;)

Comment: Using this site's search and typing "60Hz mac" this was the first result : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/413972/237687  there may be other relevant result you may wish to read. So there are a couple of useful links that you can now follow and they may confoirm the output parameters for your particular machine.

Comment: I have just googled for myself, and I have to agree with @aneuryzm that the info is very limited and unclear. Some say they were able to get higher refresh rates than 60Hz, others didn't. I would double check the cable and try all ports. Apple only talks about 60Hz and nothing else.

Comment: @SolarMike This is what I've done. Some posts say there is a limitation, other says that is possible more than 60hz. That's why I specified all exact hardware in my question.

Comment: @X_841Trust me, i doubled check a lot, and tried hdmi as well. But I've read a comment of an user succeeding with my exact same monitor and Macbook Pro using a DisplayPortCable. I'm going to add his comment to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a full 75 Hz refresh rate on 3440 x 1440 with:

- LG Ergo 34WN780 (Picture > FreeSync setting must be 'On')
- MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)
- [Delock Bidirectional USB Type-C™ to DisplayPort Cable](https://www.delock.com/produkt/86040/merkmale.html)

[image]